# Reset UItableViewCell checkmarks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

following code starts with a blank cells and add a checkmark when selected cell but, once added, if you press again that cell, it is not erased. I am trying to reset it each time that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called. How to clear cell in order to be marked only one? Thanks.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            labelInfo.text=@"1";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
            break;
        case 1:
            labelInfo.text=@"2";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
            break;
        case 2:
            labelInfo.text=@"3";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
            break;
        case 3:
            labelInfo.text=@"4";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
            break;
        case 4:
            labelInfo.text=@"5";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy-paste this. It works.

```
  //in your .h file
   int selectedCell;

   //in your .m file
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

       NSString* cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

       if(cell == nil)
       {
           cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

       }
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

       if (indexPath.section == 0) {

           if(indexPath.row == selectedCell)
           {
                   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
                   cell.selected = YES;
           }
           else
           {
               cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
               cell.selected = NO;
           }
       }
   }



   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       selectedCell = indexPath.row;
       [tableView reloadData];
       //remaining code.
   }
```

Comment: Hi, code works almost perfect excepts that default selected cell doesn't show text until another cell is pressed! How solve that?

Comment: I mean that for example, when voidDidLoad, selectedCell = 2 and that cell will not have text until any other cell is pressed.

Comment: have the value of selectedCell as -1.

Answer (score 4):

This code will remove all checkmarks on the table

```
[[self.tableView visibleCells] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setAccessoryType:) withObject:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
```

Comment: I found that UITableViewCellAccessoryNone needed to be wrapped for this to work:     [[self.tableView visibleCells] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setAccessoryType:) withObject:@(UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)];

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you start with

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Which remove check mark from selected cell, but later you assign checkmark again with

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        labelInfo.text=@"1";
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
        break;
    case 1:
        labelInfo.text=@"2";
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
        break;
    case 2:
        labelInfo.text=@"3";
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
        break;
    case 3:
        labelInfo.text=@"4";
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
        break;
    case 4:
        labelInfo.text=@"5";
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

So, you can use something like

```
 if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

for toggle the checkmark and

```
labelInfo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row + 1];
```

for label

Answer (score 0):

do this:-

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


        if (indexPath.section == 0) {

            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    labelInfo.text=@"1";
                    if (cell.accessoryType==UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) 
                        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                    else 
                        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
                    break;
                case 1:
                    labelInfo.text=@"2";
if (cell.accessoryType==UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) 
                        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                    else 
                        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
                    break;
                case 2:
                    labelInfo.text=@"3";
if (cell.accessoryType==UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) 
                        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                    else 
                        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
                    break;
                case 3:
                    labelInfo.text=@"4";
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
                    break;
                case 4:
                    labelInfo.text=@"5";
if (cell.accessoryType==UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) 
                        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                    else 
                        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```