# swift table view adding custom checkmark to cell and remove checkmark from previous cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Image view in my cell which displays a checkmark icon.

What I want to do is when you touch a cell the checkmark should appear. I got this working, but my problem now is that I can't remove the checkmark from the previous selected cell. - only one cell should be able to be selected.

I've tried to get this working in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but I can't get it right so I am stuck right now.

Update:

```
var selectedRow: NSIndexPath?

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: searchCityTableViewCell!

        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("staticCityCell") as! searchCityTableViewCell
            cell.titleLabel?.text = "Within \(stateName)"                
        }else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cityCell") as! searchCityTableViewCell
            let state = cities[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureWithStates(state)
            if indexPath == selectedRow {
                cell.cityImage.select()
            } else {
                cell.cityImage.deselect()
            }
        }

        return cell

    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        let paths:[NSIndexPath]

        if let previous = selectedRow {
            paths = [indexPath, previous]
        } else {
            paths = [indexPath]
        }
        selectedRow = indexPath
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(paths, withRowAnimation: .None)
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7172609/4475605

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Keep track of which row is currently selected.  Add a property to your ViewController:

   ```
   var selectedRow: NSIndexPath?
   ```
2. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

   ```
   let paths:[NSIndexPath]

   if let previous = selectedRow {
       paths = [indexPath, previous]
   } else {
       paths = [indexPath]
   }
   selectedRow = indexPath
   tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(paths, withRowAnimation: .None)
   ```
3. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

   ```
   if indexPath == selectedRow {
       // set checkmark image
   } else {
       // set no image
   }
   ```

An important thing to note is that the state of which row is selected should be stored in the model and not in the cell.  The table should reflect the state of the model.  In this case, the model can simply be the `indexPath` of the selected row.  Once the model is updated (`selectedRow` is set), the affected rows should reload their state.

Comment: I see one bug in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
If I select the first item in the list, then scroll down so that the item doesn't show in my screen, The item will be re-selected once I scroll back up again when it is visible in the screen again

Comment: That's not a bug. That's exactly how it should work. Why would you want the row to be deselected just because it went off screen and came back?

Comment: Thats what I mean, I (don't) want it the be de-selected just because it went off screen. Any ideas whats causing it?

Comment: It's working for me. I implemented it just as I stated in my answer and the first row stays selected when scrolling off and back again. Could you post your updated code as an update/edit to your question?

Comment: Updated. I have a hardcoded cell thats why I am checking the section. And the `select()` is a function that animates the icon by UIView.animate..
So if I would to select cell nr2, then scroll off screen and back again I will see cell nr2 being selected again. I don't now if you are missing it because you display it by hidden = true/false. But I can see my animation run twice in this case

Comment: I see the issue. You have 2 sections. The code I suggested should only apply to section 1, not section 0. To fix, have your didSelectRowAtIndexPath check the section and only do the code you currently have for section 1 only.

Comment: Selecting the row in section 0 should not count. Don't update selectedRow and don't reload the rows.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working now when I modified the section part